# Retrieve Custom Post Type taxonomy in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy, custom-post-type

I have a set of fields in my Custom Post Type **'games'** taxonomies called **'gamename'** - I am trying to retrieve this value using **query_posts** like so....

```
$args = array(
    'post_status'=>'publish',
    'post_type'=>'games',
    'gamename' => 'Space Invaders'
);
query_posts($args);

if(have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    the_title();
endwhile; else:
    echo 'No Posts!';
endif;
wp_reset_query();
```

This isnt working for me and it is just returning **'No Posts'**

Can some one suggest what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, don't use `query_posts();`, blech. use `$query = new WP_Query`, you can read up on it [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

`query_posts()` tries to be the king and overwrites global variables (EW!), the `WP_Query` class does not, however, and is considered the best (only?) way you should loop posts.

I personally (and have had colleagues) who have all had the same issue, `query_posts()` returning no posts. and 9/10 times, in the end, it's because it's overwriting global variables (namely the $post D:) which makes it return empty. And 9/10 times, using `$query = new WP_Query;` instead works!

If you are **MARRIED** to useing `query_posts()` however, try calling `wp_reset_query()` BEFORE your code too, maybe you've got a plugin or something that didn't reset it properly before your code initiates

**EDIT**

you have

```
if(have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
```

any reason you have that if statement, and not just the standard:

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
```

Comment: Thanks for that,  I have re-done things with WP_Query and everything is good :)